# Issue with dates in WCF service and in JavaSerializer decoder

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, json

One of the nastiest problems working across time zones :)

Here is my problem:

1. I have code that passes date into WCF via JSON object and I use "short" format where it contains only milliseconds since 1970 with no time zone. This DateTime parsed by WCF just FINE
2. I store date into SQL Server Database. Example: 2011-06-07 22:17:01.113 - date as I see it in SQL Server and this is perfectly fine since I store everything in UTC. So, it's (-5) time zone and date looks right.
3. I load date field into my object using EF and inside object property says it is 22:17 and Kind=Unspecified which is OK again, it is loaded from SQL, I know it is UTC but code doesn't know that so it loads this date as Unspecified.
4. I return this object to WCF client. It can be XML or it can be JSON. Here is what happen. When I JSON(this is what client specifies) - I get this: 1307503021113-0500 for date. If we convert first portion to DateTime using SQL:

> SELECT DATEADD(ss, 1307503021,
>   '1970-01-01')
>
> 2011-06-08 03:17:01.000

Part above already wrong, no? If we apply -5hr adjustment we will be back to 22:17pm which already utc time? This part already confusing to me. But what even worse - when I deserialize using JavaScriptSerializer - I see DateTime value in newly inflated object saying UTC kind and 3:17am

```
var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var returnValue = (T)oSerializer.Deserialize(s, typeof(T));
```

I'm all puzzled already and I wonder if it's possible to force WCF and other serializer/deserializers to NOT do any time offsets and stuff? I'd rather format all dates for display manually and I want to store UTC dates in database.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like WCF thinks that if DateKind is Unspecified than it's LOCAL.
I did this: After I got objects from EF I specified Kind:

```
foreach (var tu in tripUpdates)
                {
                    tu.DeviceTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(tu.DeviceTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
```

That fixed it - now when WCF serves object it doesn't include timezone which is GREAT. Now my main question is there any way to specify Kind on EF entities somehow so I don't have to manually specifiy kind for every date in service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the datetime via a SELECT statement always set the DateTime.Kind to UTC.  This way WCF/XML will not try to adjust the time.

Comment: see my update. I did. Now I wonder how to handle this auto-magically :)

Comment: Perhaps that is another question?

Comment: @katit can you ask that question please? :)

Comment: @wal - I already googled - looks like there is no way to do it in EF. One option is to move to DateTimeOffset but it's more trouble than it's worth. I have my own hand-written classes to use for JSON - I just put code to specify Kind there and will be done with it..